# AB amplifier, spice not giving what I expected

Tags: amplifier, ltspice

Boy, I've copied this common circuit from elsewhere and spice is giving me this strange result. Below are the two voltages on the bases in blue and green. In red is Vout. I'm puzzled why Vout is only doing something when both bases are on. Hence the overlapping of the waveforms. I believe the bases are biased correctly, there's 50 mA on the resistors. In any case, I thought AB amplifiers were supposed to do the opposite of this, and not just output AND logic.

Does anyone have any ideas?

[image: ab sim]

Comment: Your oscilloscope does not show actual voltages.

Comment: Your oscilloscope does not show actual voltages. Your 22nF for C2 cuts levels below 7200Hz but your input signal is only 50Hz. Increase the capacitance of C2 to  4.7uF then reduce the input signal level. Only amplifiers in a school project have the input signal fed to between the diodes. Your output transistors are missing driver transistors to feed them.

Comment: Either use darlington NPNs & PNPs, or you'll have to make R2,R3 much lower-value to get enough base current.

Comment: I changed/removed c2 and there is no difference. BTW I'm trying to do a simple amp design with not too many parts because i have to make 6 of these.

Comment: Don’t use the default transistor and diode models, change them to models of real devices.  If you know what transistors you plan to use see if you can get models for them.

Comment: Also can you show the voltage scale on the left of the plot. I think you may be overdriving it. Is the input 100 V peak to peak?

Comment: input is 80v. thats the voltage i can get from my voltage amplification stage.

Comment: Do you get what you expect if you change the load to 800ohm? If so, then try what @glen_geek suggested. You have tons of headroom with plus/minus 45V so darlington won’t make a dent in your output range.

Comment: @noobboob Replace your two 1k resistors with 100 Ohm, instead, and make C2 470 uF. Then don't use 80 Vpk for the source but try 40 Vpk (or so.) The whole design is only for education, not for real. The 1k resistors are your only source/sink of current for the output BJTs and what those resistors can source/sink will vary with respect to the signal. This isn't a good place to be. Alter the design.

Comment: Many simple audio power amplifiers use an NPN transistor for your R2 then it can drive the base of the PNP output transistor almost to the negative supply voltage, then use a Bootstrap circuit to replace your R1 then the base voltage of the NPN output transistor can go higher than the positive supply voltage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's pretend Q1 has current gain \$\beta=100\$, and then examine what happens as the input potential rises. I'll focus on only the upper half, the "pushing" half of the push/pull pair:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw4z5e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By inspection we can predict certain behaviour. All base current \$I_B\$ must come via R1, whose current \$I_A\$ will be split into two paths (due to KCL), D1 and Q1's base. Therefore R1 places an upper limit on the current available for Q1's base.

We can see that when output \$V_{OUT}\$ is close to 0V, collector current \$I_C\$ will be at a minimum, as will base current \$I_B\$, since \$I_C=\beta I_B\$. You no doubt already understand that as your desired output potential \$V_{OUT}\$ rises, collector current \$I_C\$ also rises, due to load R2, and the base current \$I_B\$ necessary to achieve that also rises, albeit \$\beta=100\$ times less. Still, the key thing to grasp is that \$I_B\$ rises with output \$V_{OUT}\$

On the input side, as input potential \$V_{IN}\$ rises, the voltage across R1 \$V_{R1}\approx (50V)-V_{IN}\$ is *decreasing*, and so must current \$I_A=\frac{V_{R1}}{R_1}\$. As we established above, \$I_B\$ is derived from \$I_A\$, and if \$I_A\$ is falling, while the necessary base current \$I_B\$ is rising, there must surely be a point where the two "meet". A point where \$I_A\$ is only just sufficient to provide adequate \$I_B\$, and beyond which Q1's base becomes starved of current. In this next graph I sweep \$V_{IN}\$ from 0V to +50V, and plot \$I_A\$ (blue, as measured on AMa), and \$I_B\$ (orange, measured by AMb):

[image]

At some point those traces must "meet", a point where \$I_A=I_B\$. This is clearly visible at around \$V_{IN}\approx +25V\$. As \$V_{IN}\$ continues to rise past this point, base potential \$V_B\$ has also reached a maximum, and can't rise any further. D1 becomes reverse biased, and further rise of \$V_{IN}\$ has no effect. This can be seen in a plot of \$V_B\$ (blue) and \$V_{OUT}\$ (orange):

[image]

Clearly, then, this circuit will clip output potential at about +25V. The lower half of the push-pull pair will behave similarly for the negative going half of the waveform. This is why you see the "clipped" output you see in red in your simulation. The inability of base potential \$V_B\$ to continue to rise, after the condition \$I_A=I_B\$ is reached, can be seen in your green trace.

There are a few things you can do to improve output swing:

- Reduce R1. This increases available base current, but also increases quiescent current \$I_A\$ when \$V_{IN}=0V\$. This is very inefficient.
- Use a transistor with higher current gain, or even use a darlington pair.
- replace R1 with a constant current source, providing sufficient \$I_A\$ (and consequently \$I_B\$) across the entire required output voltage range. For example, if you require the output to swing all the way to +40V, with load R2=8Ω, then you also require \$I_C=\frac{40V}{8\Omega}=5A\$. This corresponds to base current \$I_B=\frac{I_C}{\beta}=50mA\$. If you replace R1 with a 50mA constant current source, then this circuit will clip at around \$V_{OUT}=40V\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVln9z.png)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Great. I may try a different design next, but the constant current idea will no doubt come in handy. It'd be funny if I could get this dumb textbook example to actually work well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So now that I've had a chance to simulate this, I'll address the issue of why the output voltage is so far below the input voltage, which is your main question.

As I suspected your signal voltage is far too high. When asked, you said:

> input is 80v. thats the voltage i can get from my voltage amplification stage.

In LTspice if you put 80 V for a Sine wave source's amplitude it will be 80 V ***peak***. That means 160 V\$_{pk-pk}\$, far more than your amplifier could handle. You need to reduce that down to something more reasonable, you have 45 V supplies and you need to leave some headroom so the amplitude should be maybe 40 V max.

That said, there's still other issues, biasing, using correct models, circuit topology, temperature sensitivity, etc. You'll probably end up with something much more complicated than you wanted, so you might take a look at dedicated audio amp ICs, maybe Class D.

Comment: ok thanks, i see now the 80v input was too much, i meant it to be 40. with that change made, i still get the same issue, so i think you lot are correct in just going with a different design. i tried this one because it was one of the simplest.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I made most of my simple power amplifiers but today I used power amplifier ICs.[image]